# About EulerAngles Conversion from Eigen C++ Library

Tags: c++, eigen

Suppose that I have a 3-dimensional frame with rotation roll = 0, pitch = 0 and yaw = 0 about x, y and z axis respectively.

I want the frame to rotate about x-axis for 3.14159 (Pi) or roll = Pi.

Below is the code for said situation.

The problem is, when I want to convert the rotation matrix back to roll, pitch, and yaw, the code gives different answer.

Instead of roll = Pi, the result is roll = 0, pitch = pi, and yaw = pi.

I think RVC toolbox by Peter Corke on Matlab gives correct answer.

Maybe something is not right with with my program or eulerAngles in Eigen works differently? Please help.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

const double PI = 3.14159265359;

int main()
{
    using ::Eigen::AngleAxisd;
    using ::Eigen::Matrix3d;
    using ::Eigen::Vector3d;
    using ::std::cout;
    using ::std::endl;

    Matrix3d R,Rx;

    R = AngleAxisd(PI, Vector3d::UnitX())
        * AngleAxisd(0, Vector3d::UnitY())
        * AngleAxisd(0, Vector3d::UnitZ());
    Rx = AngleAxisd(PI, Vector3d::UnitX());

    cout << R << endl << endl;
    cout << Rx << endl << endl;

    Vector3d ea = R.eulerAngles(0,1,2); 
    Vector3d eax = Rx.eulerAngles(0,1,2); 

    cout << ea << endl << endl;
    cout << eax << endl << endl;

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Output (I round off numbers which are too small to zero):

```
1 0 0
0 -1 0
0 0 -1

1 0 0
0 -1 0
0 0 -1

0
3.14159
3.14159

0
3.14159
3.14159
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html#gad118fececd448d7485ffea4858775e5a) of `Eigen:eulerAngles`. Details on various conventions of Euler-angles is well documented in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html).

Edit:

1. You will get exact results if you use `M_PI`, which is internally defined, instead of truncated value of PI.
2. The Euler-angle representation suffers from singularity. The test case that you are trying to compare is a singular position.
3. You may want to use quaternions or axis-angle representation if you wish to overcome the singularities.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but I think you gave a wrong information and this can be misleading. Take a look at my code again.

Comment: Sorry! I should have tried the code. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Euler's angles are not unique. In your XYZ convention, both `(0, pi, pi)` and `(pi,0,0)` represents the same rotation, and both are correct. The `Eigen::eulerAngles` method consistently chooses to minimize first angles.

Comment: I see. Yup, confirmed it when using (0,pi,pi) and it gave about the same rotation matrix with (pi,0,0). Is there any workaround to this so that Eigen::eulerAngles not to minimize the first angles?

Answer (score -1):

Different order euler angles(roll1, pitch1, yaw1 or pitch2, yaw2, roll2, ...) can result in the same rotation matrix.

Actually, the Eigen document gave the answer.
Read the function declaration of [Eigen document](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html#gac3d90b12b21e1aaa2a9de9b0e45e6b7c) more carefully, and you will get the answer.

`Matrix< typename MatrixBase< Derived >::Scalar, 3, 1 > Eigen::MatrixBase< Derived >::eulerAngles    (   Index   a0,
        Index   a1,
        Index   a2 
    )       const`

Each of the three parameters a0,a1,a2 represents the respective rotation axis as an integer in {0,1,2}. For instance, in:

`Vector3f ea = mat.eulerAngles(2, 0, 2);`

"2" represents the z axis and "0" the x axis, etc